# record of email notifications sent out (webform / postfix)

Tags: webforms, emails

I have a webform with example.com/node/123/webform/emails set to send email notification from info@example.com to several email addresses when a submission is received.

Is there a way to see a record of email notifications sent out ie with date and time etc to verify that the notifications have in fact been sent?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My favorite and so far most reliable, if not most convenient, way to achieve that is out of Drupal, actually. If you set it up inside Drupal, and you hit some errors, you never are 100% certain if mail wasn't sent, or just wasn't logged. Or, if logging happens first, you can never know for sure if mail was sent, or was only supposed to be.

The way I prefer to do it is to use external SMTP server for outgoing mail. That way I can be sure all mail I have logged actually was sent from Drupal, and chance I logged all mail are bigger, too. After all, SMTP servers have decades of evolution more than Drupal, or even PHP. Added bonuses include:

- Less CPU and memory use on webserver, because it does not need code for mail log, and this code would be loaded on each uncached request.
- Ability to deliver mail even if recipient's server is temporarily down.

## Example

If you have business Gmail, you can use [SMTP Authentication Support](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) module to make your site send via Gmail, and you will see mail sent from site in your Sent Mail, just like this:

[image: screenshot]

No special configuration was needed to get this working. You can use full power of Google if you do so: filters, labels, whatever you wish.

If you will use company mail server, just make sure your sysadmin will configure it in similar manner.

Comment: @ Molot thanks I am interested in this - does that mean using https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp and something like mandrill.com ? I am googling but please let me know any helpful links re setup etc

Comment: @Juc1 see my updated answer

Comment: @ Molot wow that is cool - I will try with gmail where I am using business Gmail and also I am looking into https://www.drupal.org/project/mandrill

Comment: @Juc1 glad to help. Happy coincidence you are actually using Gmail, too :D I never used mandrill, but I've heard it is good, but only worth the money if your traffic is significant enough to justify prices.

Comment: @ Molot I have setup Mandrill - I think you get the first 12,000 emails per month for free - if anyone is interested there are some nice set up instructions here http://redcrackle.com/blog/send-drupals-transactional-emails-using-mandrill

Answer (score 2):

Webform doesn't provide default functionality for it.

you can use either of these modules to log outgoing mail:

- [Mail Log](https://drupal.org/project/maillog)
- [Email Log](https://drupal.org/project/emaillog)

Comment: @ Pravin thanks  for your reply - I don't like www.drupal.org/project/emaillog because it is only rc-1 and 37 sites using it. I tried https://drupal.org/project/maillog - it works fine for some emails sent out eg new comment but so far does not seem to work for webform new submission (ie no log).